# Ballerina's straight back

Tags: back, ballet

Is a straight back, as it is the case of ballet and also gymnasts, the result of stronger muscles or just a case of learning the  "Correct Stance", that is, how to keep your back straight?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by straight back without pictures (do you mean generally, or when they're holding specific poses?), but I know in some gymnastic based programs, they recommend training a position called the Hollow Body position.

[image]

It involves flattening the back against the ground with resistance provided by the rest of your body.

My understanding is that it leads to a "straighter" body when performing a handstand (and presumably other positions as well)

[image]